What would be the best way to export 11M records in one go on Odoo.sh
We want to export 11M records in odoo in a single export operation, what would be the best way to do this on odoo.sh v17 latest with 1 worker currently.
I am expecting to export 11M records to be exported in a single operation without timeout.
